# Merge two tables with same structure and numers sum

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello i have two tables with same structure and now I want merge it.

Here is structure:
[image: table structure]

Terms:

**steamid** - that goes without saying

**regcas** - keep only a smaller value

**VIP** - sum

**FunVIP** - *ignore when duplicate*

**Days** - sum

**KilledCT** - sum

**WinPP** - sum

**LastT** - sum

**cas** - sum

**lastnick** - *ignore when duplicate*

**lastlog** - *ignore when duplicate*

**ct_cas** - sum

**simon_cas** - sum

**Example when duplicate:**

*row from main table*

```
steamid            | regcas      | VIP | FunVIP | Days | KilledCT | WinPP | LastT | lastnick | lastlog    | ct_cas | simon_cas
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
76561198040874389  | 1546639030  | 1   | 0      | 125  | 1000     | 20    | 50    | Bomber   | 1546639037 | 64     | 50
```

*row from second table*

```
steamid            | regcas      | VIP | FunVIP | Days | KilledCT | WinPP | LastT | lastnick | lastlog    | ct_cas | simon_cas
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
76561198040874389  | 1553888234  | 1   | 5      | 100  | 1555     | 40    | 20    | Lucker   | 1549387793 | 10     | 1
```

**Result**

```
steamid            | regcas      | VIP | FunVIP | Days | KilledCT | WinPP | LastT | lastnick | lastlog    | ct_cas | simon_cas
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
76561198040874389  | 1546639030  | 2   | 0      | 225  | 2555     | 60    | 70    | Bomber   | 1546639037 | 74     | 51
```

I absolutely don't know how to compose a complex SQL statement and I need help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by merging? Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: UNION ALL the tables. GROUP BY the result.

Comment: How do you know which lastnick to chose? The one from main table?

Comment: @jarlh just i want ignore FunVIP, lastlog, lastnick when duplicing

Comment: Ignore? Do you mean you want to keep the FunVIP, lastlog, lastnick values from main table?

Comment: @jarlh Yes exactly

Comment: Can a steamid exist in second table only? (Or will it always exist in main table?)

Comment: yes some steamid is exists only in second table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want `union all` and `group by`.  I have no idea what "ignore with duplicate" is supposed to mean, but `min()` seems close enough.  So:

```
select steamid, min(regcas) as regcas, sum(vip) as vip), 
       min(FunVIP) as FunVIP,
       sum(Days) as days, sum(KilledCT) as KilledCT, sum(WinPP) as WinPP,
       sum(LastT) as LastT, sum(cas) as cas,
       min(lastnick) as lastnick,
       min(lastlog) as lastlog,
       sum(ct_cas) as ct_cas, sum(simon_cas) as simon_cas
from ((select t1.* from table1 t1) union all
      (select t2.* from table2 t2)
     ) t2
group by steamid;
```

Answer (score 0):

To merge two tables.Can use join tables command.

**select*from natural join ;**

```
              OR [1]
```

**select*from, where column.table1=column.table2;**

Comment: Please add more details such as example, sample data etc.

Comment: @mohdatif will do it next time